# Preventing pool processes from importing __main__ and globals

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using a multiprocessing pool of workers as a part of a much larger application. Since I use it for crunching a large volume of simple math, I have a shared-nothing architecture, where the only variables the workers ever need are passed on as arguments. Thus, I do not need the worker subprocesses to import any globals, my `__main__` module or, consequently, any of the modules it imports. Is there any way to force such a behavior and avoid the performance hit when spawning the pool?

I should note that my environment is Win32, which lacks `os.fork()` and the worker processes are spawned *"using a subprocess call to sys.executable (i.e. start a new Python process) followed by serializing all of the globals, and sending those over the pipe."* as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765129/hows-python-multiprocessing-implemented-on-windows). This being said, I want to do as little of the above as possible so my pool opens faster.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [`multiprocessing.forking`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/multiprocessing/forking.py) implementation, particularly `get_preparation_data` and `prepare` (win32-specific), globals aren't getting pickled. The reimport of the parent process's `__main__` is a bit ugly, but it won't run any code except the one at the toplevel; not even `if __name__ == '__main__'` clauses. So just keep the main module without import-time side-effects.

---

You can prevent your main module from importing anything when the subprocess starts, too (only useful on win32 which, as you note, can't fork). Move the `main()` and its imports to a separate module, so that the startup script contains only:

```
if '__name__' == '__main__':
    from mainmodule import main
    main()
```

There is still an implicit `import site` in the child process startup. It does important initialisation and I don't think mp.forking has an easy way to disable it, but I don't expect it to be expensive anyway.

Comment: What you are saying is true and putting your main code in a `__name__ == '__main__'` clause goes without saying but there *has* to be an explicit way or at least a set of best practices that reduce the start-up time of the subprocesses.

Comment: @kaloyan I don't think you have much that needs to be reduced; but I've added one more thing that goes without saying, which is that you can also guard the imports with that clause.