# How to route logging messages from the multiprocessing module to a file?

Tags: python, file, logging, multiprocessing

In the [Python docs I found that logging messages](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#logging) are possible in python scripts that use the multiprocessing module to spawn different processes.

```
import multiprocessing
import logging

logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

So `logger.warning('doomed')` would give me the message `'doomed'`, but only to the console.

**How can I switch the log-messages to a file?**

Comment: Did you check the documentation at `logging.basicConfig`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiprocess logging isn't trivial, but isn't difficult either. You'll need the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module.

The main point is to have a listener process that will receive all the logging records through [multiprocessing queues](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue). This listener process will then handle those records with whathever internal handlers you'll decide to use. In your case you may want to use a [`FileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) or similar.

If you are in Python 3.2 or later version you'll have both [`QueueHandler`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler) and [`QueueListener`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.handlers.html#queuelistener) in the standard libary. `Quelistener` is the listener process that I was talking about before (yes, it does have a `start()` method).

If you are on a previous Python version take a look at this [link](http://plumberjack.blogspot.it/2010/09/using-logging-with-multiprocessing.html) that basically shows how to rewrite them (and how to use them).

---

If you want a references from the official doc, take a look at the [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) session from the [Logging Cookbook](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html).

You may also be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/894284/1132524) from the question [How should I log while using multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/641420/1132524)