# Python 3: Using a multiprocessing queue for logging

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

I've recently been given the challenge of working multiprocessing into our software. I want a main process to spawn subprocesses, and I need some way of sending logging information back to the main process. This is mainly because a module we use writes warning and error messages to a logging object, and we want these messages to appear in the gui, which runs in the main process.

The obvious approach was to write a small class with a write() method that puts() onto a queue, and then use this class in a logging stream handler. The main process would then get() from this queue to send the text to the gui. But this didn't seem to work, and I don't know why

I wrote some sample code to demonstrate the problem. It uses a logging object to write a queue in a subprocess, and then the main process tries to read from the queue, but fails. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with this?

```
import time, multiprocessing, queue, logging

class FileLikeQueue:
    """A file-like object that writes to a queue"""
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q
    def write(self, t):
        self.q.put(t)
    def flush(self):
        pass


def func(q):
    """This function just writes the time every second for five 
    seconds and then returns. The time is sent to the queue and 
    to a logging object"""

    stream = FileLikeQueue(q)

    log = logging.getLogger()
    infohandler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
    infohandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    infoformatter = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
    infohandler.setFormatter(infoformatter)
    log.addHandler(infohandler)

    t1 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t1 < 5: #run for five seconds
        log.info('Logging: ' + str(time.time()))
        q.put('Put: %s' % str(time.time()))
        time.sleep(1)



def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    #read the queue until it is empty
    while True:
        try:
            t = q.get()
        except queue.Empty:
            break
        print(t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Logging: 1333629221.01
Put: 1333629221.01
Logging: 1333629222.02
Put: 1333629222.02
Logging: 1333629223.02
Put: 1333629223.02
Logging: 1333629224.02
Put: 1333629224.02
Logging: 1333629225.02
Put: 1333629225.02
```

But what I get is:

```
Put: 1333629221.01
Put: 1333629222.02
Put: 1333629223.02
Put: 1333629224.02
Put: 1333629225.02
```

So the put() operation in func() works, but the logging doesn't. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't dig into your code, but if you are trying to logging in a multriprocessing environment you may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9823098/1132524), that I wrote not long ago, useful.

Comment: Thanks for this Rik, this is helpful too.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with the configuration of the logging module:

You need to call `log.setLevel(logging.INFO)`. The default log level is `WARNING`, so your logs have no effect.

You did call `setLevel` on the handler object, but the logged messages never reach the handler because they are filtered by the logger. There is no need to call `setLevel` on the handler itself, because it processes all messages by default.