# logging while using parallel python

Tags: python, logging, parallel-python

I'm using parallel python to execute a big function (`executePipeline`) multiple times. This function is also using multiprocessing (with the `multiprocessing` module).
I'm having some trouble to display correctly the logging messages on my console using the parallel python module. When I'm not using it, the logging messages are well displayed.

Here is how it works. I have a server who is calling a worker every time it gets a request from  client using:

```
job = self.server.job_server.submit(func = executeWorker, args = (config, ) )
```

This function is execute from a new thread every time there is a new request from a client.
Then the worker is calling the function `executePipeline` which is executing different processus using multiprocessing.

The server a `SocketServer.TCPServer` I using threading. I set up a logger in my server as following using the root logger:

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger()
self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
self.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler() 
self.job_server = pp.Server(ncpus = 8) # for test
self.jobs = []
```

When I'm running my server i can only get the logging from the `executePipeline` but not from the child processes.
Also I get the logging of the execute pipeline only at the end of the job not while is running.

Also here is the worker code. The `"Executing pipeline with worker number "` is well displayed in my terminal

```
'''
Setup logging
'''

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  

# worker name
publicIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) 
pid = os.getpid()
workerID = unicode(str(publicIP) + ":" + str(pid))

logger.info( "Executing pipeline with worker {}".format(workerID))
res = executePipeline(config)    
markedScore = res["marker.score"]
markedDetails = res["marker.detail"]
results = {'marker.detail' : markedDetails , 'marker.score' : markedScore } 

return results
```

Is there a good way too get the logging working properly and see what the child process of my `executePipeline` function are sending back?

Thanks for your help!

Romanzo

Comment: I think I could help, but I'm afraid I do not understand your question. I guess it boils down to "get the logger working in the subprocesses created by executePipeline", but you never showed the code of this function. Or did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when I tried to write paralellised tests which write results to a shared dictionary. The **multiprocessing.Manager** was the answer:

```
# create shared results dictionary
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
result_dict = manager.dict({})
```

so you can simply post the logs from processes to that common dictionary and then process them.

or use `LOG = multiprocessing.get_logger()` as explained here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
and here: [How should I log while using multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python)