# Global variables lost in Bottle route

Tags: python, scope, bottle

I'm using Bottle as Python web framework.

Basically, here is what I am doing :

**auth.py** :

```
from bottle import get

logger = None
webserver = None

def load(server):
    global logger, webserver

    logger = server.getLogger('auth')
    webserver = server

@get('/auth')
def auth():
    logger.debug('Entering route')
```

**webserver.py** :

```
import bottle
import imp

class WebServer(object):
    # ...

    def getLogger(self, name):
        # ...

    def start_wsgi(self):
        # ...

        app = bottle.default_app()

        mod = imp.load_source('auth', 'auth.py')
        mod.load(self)

        # ...

        return app

    # ...

ws = WebServer()
app = ws.start_wsgi()
```

*NB: no error handling or extra code here, I just exposed what is interesting to the issue (in my opinion)*

It seems that the global scope is not shared between the main process (which runs the `WebServer` code) and the thread handling the request (`logger` is still `None` when I hit the `/auth` URL).

By printing `id(logger)` in function `load()` and route `auth()` (with a `global logger` added, just to be sure), I get two different ids.

How can I share my loggers to the threads handling the request ?

**PS:** I tried adding a field to the default Bottle application, like this :

```
app = default_app()
app.logger = # mylogger
```

And then in the route :

```
app = default_app()
app.logger.debug('Message')
```

But it seems that even the `default_app()` is different.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I share my loggers to the threads handling the request ?
>
> ...
>
> By printing id(logger) in function load() and route auth() (with a global logger added, just to be sure), I get two different ids.

That's okay--your logger variables need not reference the same logger object for things to work properly across threads.

Each thread should just acquire its logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('foo.bar.baz')
```

That will work just fine.  (Across *threads*, mind you, [not across processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python).)

Btw, I'm not sure what your `Webserver.getLogger` function returns, but in any case this function seems unnecessary.

P.S., Just curious--Are you actually seeing a problem with your logging output, or were you just surprised when you observed that the `id`s of the different logger variables were not identical?

Comment: The function ``Webserver.getLogger`` initialize the logger to the same logging level used in the ``Webserver`` class. And I still need the global reference to ``webserver`` (same issue as ``logger``)

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm not clear exactly what you're asking.  What's stopping you from referencing `webserver`?

Comment: That's the point of the question, in the route ``/auth``, ``webserver`` and ``logger`` are ``None`` even if the ``load()`` function was called by the webserver.

Comment: ANy solutions to this?

Comment: Need to see what `getLogger` returns.  Can't run this code (to reproduce) otherwise.

Comment: ``getLogger`` is not the problem since both ``logger`` and ``webserver`` are ``None`` in ``/auth``. But it just perform a ``logging.getLogger`` followed by a ``logger.setLevel(self.loglevel)``