# log handlers missing in windows

Tags: python, windows, logging

I'm trying to understand why the same set of code works in osx but not in windows.

```
logger_name = 'gic_scheduler'
logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=os.path.join(tmp_folder, 'scheduler.log'), encoding='utf-8')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

executor_logger = logging.getLogger('apscheduler.executors.default')
executor_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
executor_logger.addHandler(ch)
executor_logger.addHandler(fh)

executors = {'default': ProcessPoolExecutor(5)}

scheduler = BlockingScheduler(executors=executors, logger=logger)

scheduler.add_job(go, 'interval', seconds=5)    
scheduler.start()
```

In particular, no output is produced by the logger 'apscheduler.executors.default'. I digged into the 3rd party library using this logger and printed out `logger.handlers` and in OSX's case the handlers are there but in Windows they are empty. Any ideas why?

```
def run_job(job, jobstore_alias, run_times, logger_name):
    """Called by executors to run the job. Returns a list of scheduler events to be dispatched by the scheduler."""

    events = []
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    print logger_name
    print logger.handlers
```

Comment: Probably you're relying on the logging configuration getting inherited via `fork`, but Windows *spawns* new process via `CreateProcess`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1009560) for a `logging.Handler` subclass that uses a `multiprocessing.Queue`. The pool initializer sets up the handler and logging level in each worker process.

Comment: yes @eryksun, apparently I missed the documentation where logging configurations does not pass over to child processes. If u put it as an answer I'll accept it.