# save error compile message in txt file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you help me that when I compile my program and if I have an error how can I redirect this error message in text file, before compilation terminate?

I wrote this code, But my problem is i want when i have an error after that my COMP_ERR.txt file create and write error inside this file.
but in my code this create before

```
import urllib.request
import os
import tempfile
import sys
import fileinput


original_stderr = sys.stderr
f_error = open("COMP_ERR.txt", "w")
sys.stderr = f_error
try:
    url = sys.argv[1]
    path_snip_file = sys.argv[2]

    #url = 'http://pages.di.unipi.it/corradini/Didattica/AP-17/PROG-ASS/03/ClassWithTest.java'
    #path_snip_file = "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/snip1.java"

    path_remote_file_inOurComp = "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/ClassWithTest.java"
    path_remote_file_inOurCom = "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/ClassWithTest1.java"
    gt_url = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)

    print("the URL is: ") 
    print(gt_url)
    link = input("input the path of file: ")

    """
    f = open(link, "r")
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
    f.close()
    """

    #--------------------]
    #copy snipper java file inside remote file
    #[--------------------


    with open(path_remote_file_inOurComp, 'w') as modify_file:
        with open (link, 'r') as r_file:
            for line in r_file:
                if " public static void main(" not in line:
                    modify_file.write(line)
                else:
                    with open(path_snip_file, 'r') as snip_file:
                        for lines in snip_file:
                            modify_file.write(lines)
                    modify_file.write('\n'+line)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------
    #refactor
    #-------------------------------------------------------------
    with open(path_remote_file_inOurCom, 'w') as ft:
        with open(path_remote_file_inOurComp, 'r') as file_n:
            for line in file_n:
                line = line.replace("System.out.println(", "System.out.println(insertLength(")
                line = line.replace(";", ");")
                ft.write(line)


except IndexError:
    print("Not enough input! ! !")
sys.stderr = original_stderr
f_error.close()
```

Comment: looking for this https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html ???

Comment: What are you compiling?

Comment: if i understand what you mean exactly, i compiled .py file

Answer (score 0):

```
logf = open("download.log", "w")
for download in download_list:
    try:
        # code to process download here
    except Exception as e:     # most generic exception you can catch
        logf.write("Failed to download {0}: {1}\n".format(str(download), str(e)))
        # optional: delete local version of failed download
    finally:
        # optional clean up code
        pass
```

apart from this approach, you can use logging library to save each and every logs of your application.

Following is the method 2 of the problem of saving logs.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='gunicon-server.log',level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(levelname)s]: [%(asctime)s] [%(message)s]', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
try:
    # code to process download here
except Exception as e:     # most generic exception you can catch
    logging.error(str(e))
finally:
    # optional clean up code
    pass
```

Comment: Opening a log file in write ("w") mode is a bad approach, Generally logs are stored at-least 10 years for security purposes. write mode will truncate the past data in the log file.

Comment: then append mode will be good or some other please suggest @  VISWESWARAN NAGASIVAM

Comment: i even suggested the logging library. whatever the use case of the user.

Comment: I would suggest you to use logging library provided python since it supports multiple threads, but even python's default library wont support logging in multiprocessing, there are some workarounds(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python)

Comment: Logging library even provides better levels of logging like DEBUG, ERROR, INFO which we can set and have logs in a very organized manner with the timestamp.

Comment: i read before logging.error() but i did not understand how can i use them in this situation that when i have error build my text file and write errors inside this file and before error do not build text file

Comment: i am editing my answer with the logging approach.. which is much more efficient.

Comment: checkout the method 2 to check your solution in logging.error().

Comment: @user8903246 did this answer helped you ??

Comment: thank you so much.yes it was too much helpful for me

Comment: @user8903246 then please hit that green tick button.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is useful to you

```
import sys
try:
   raise
except Exception as err:
      **exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()**  # this is to get error line number and description.
      file_name = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]  # to get File Name.
      error_string="ERROR : Error Msg:{},File Name : {}, Line no : {}\n".format(err,file_name,exc_tb.tb_lineno))
      file_log = open("error_log.log", "a")
      file_log.write(error_string)
      file_log.close()
```

Comment: could you tell me how can i define for program that what is my filename? because i want redirect to text file

Comment: I used logging for redirect to text file and for this you have define in filename='your text file name'. like this:    logging.basicConfig(filename="YOUR TEXT FILE NAME.TXT", level= logging.ERROR) and i have to point that i did chose the level of ERROR but you can choose another level

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open('errorlog.txt', 'w')

# do whatever

sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

see this for more details  : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=849752