# Multiprocessing messes up logging to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing

#### Issue

Multiprocessing messes up logging to file:

1. Lines already written may be removed
2. New lines may not be written
3. Order of lines may be incorrect

Logging works fine if I don't use multiprocessing.

I read that I can use a [QueueHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler), but I want to understand why writing logging to some handler still messes up another handler.

#### Code to reproduce

Set `USE_MP=False` or uncomment `exit()` to verify that logging works fine as long as multiprocessing lines are not executed.

```py
import logging
import multiprocessing
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from typing import Dict, List

USE_MP = True

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(filename="test.log", mode="w"))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

mplogger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
mplogger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
mplogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def time_consuming_function(file_name):
    logger.info(f"Running time_consuming_function with {file_name}")
    time.sleep(1)
    return file_name, file_name


def mp(file_names: List[str]) -> Dict[str, str]:
    logger.info(f"Running mp...")
    with Pool() as p:
        return {
            file_name: file_name
            for file_name, file_name in p.imap_unordered(
                time_consuming_function, file_names
            )
        }


def non_mp(file_names: List[str]) -> Dict[str, str]:
    logger.info(f"Running non-mp...")
    return {
        file_name: file_name
        for file_name, file_name in map(time_consuming_function, file_names)
    }


def main():
    logger.info("Start run...")
    file_names = list("ABCDE")
    # exit()
    if USE_MP:
        mp(file_names)
    else:
        non_mp(file_names)
    logger.info("End run.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Python version: 3.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I log while using multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand why writing logging to some handler still messes up another handler.

It's explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) in the Python documentation, assuming that you're talking about file-related handlers. You can use `QueueHandler` with a `QueueListener`, or you can use a `SocketHandler` with a suitable listener. The documentation contains [info on running a logging socket listener in production](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#running-a-logging-socket-listener-in-production) and even has a link to [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/vsajip/4b227eeec43817465ca835ca66f75e2b) with files you can download and experiment with / adapt to your needs.