# Python multiprocessing log file is empty

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-logging

Below is my dummy script. It works fine, but the log file is empty even post running. What is wrong? I am assuming it to be related to the multiprocessing logger but not able to figure out yet.

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import traceback
import logging

def get_ids():
    return [i for i in range(100)]

def function_name(ids):
    if ids[0] % 4 == 0:
        raise Exception(f"Error processing chunk starting with id {ids[0]}")
    
    # Do some processing here
    print(f"Processing chunk starting with id {ids[0]}")
    return

def process_chunk(chunk):
    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    try:
        function_name(chunk)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Error processing chunk {chunk}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'example.log'))
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_path, level=logging.DEBUG)

    ids = get_ids()
    chunks = [ids[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(ids), 5)]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
    for chunk in chunks:
        pool.apply(process_chunk, args=(chunk,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the log file?

Comment: I am raising exception manually if you see, atleast that should be captured? I am using debug level in logging!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750694/271415

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def process_chunk(chunk):
    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    handler = logging.FileHandler(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "76147452.log")
    )

    # Avoid duplicated messages in the output
    if len(logger.handlers) == 0:
        logger.addHandler(handler)

    try:
        function_name(chunk)
    except Exception as e:
       logger.exception(f"Error processing chunk {chunk}")
```

Also, see [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this topic, but it seems like this problem is mentioned in the docs for [`multiprocessing.get_logger()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_logger): "Messages sent to this logger will not by default propagate to the root logger." So you just need to [enable propagation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate):

```
def process_chunk(chunk):
    try:
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_path = ...
    logging.basicConfig(...)

    logger = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    logger.propagate = True

    ...
```

I'm also getting `logger` in the global scope here, which starts its logging earlier, but I'm not sure if it has any other effect.