# Parallel processing with strange log results

Tags: python, threadpool

When run the threadded version of a script :

```
while(conf['loop']):
    for (_,_,whole_tit) in os.walk(dir_base+conf['dirr']):
        break
        
    # with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cores) as executor:  
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cores) as executor:
        executor.map(parallel_master_routine, whole_tit)
```

where parallel_master_routine contain other function in which in cascade contains a function is deemed to save a kind of sequetial log file through the aggiorna_tit. This funcion keep trace if in the log already exist an istance, in the case, skip it to allows print in on a next step a fresh istance.

```
    ......
an = dir_base+conf['dir_conf']+'Analisi_models'+'.csv'
            try:
                if not os.path.isfile(an):
                    open(an,'w').close()
                aggiorna_tit(an,dir_base+conf['dir_conf']+'_Analisi_model_'+'.csv',tit,net)
           except:
                pass
            with open(an,'a') as f:
                dt = datetime.datetime.now()
                f.write(str(dt)+'§'+tit+'§'+net+'§'+'pred/orig'+'§'+",".join([str(i) for i in data_predict])+'§'+",".join([str(i) for i in y_test])+'§'+str(pct_nul)+"\n")

def aggiorna_tit(t_in,t_out,tit,net):
    if not os.path.exists(t_in):
        open(t_in,'a').close()
    with open(t_in, "r") as input:
        input = input.readlines()
    ex = [e for e in input if not '§'+str(tit)+'§'+str(net)+'§' in e ] 
    x = "".join(ex)
    with open(t_out, "w") as output:
        output.write(x)
    # replace file with original name
    os.replace(t_out, t_in)
```

The point:
When I run the sequential version (within a common for cycle), I obtain a clean and well formatted log file, when instead is the threadded script to run with same sub functions, the log file results as a kind of pickled-meat formatted: truncated lines inside, numbers of lines that keep constant instead of increase, and other unlogical (for me) things.

I was thinking is due of the ThreadPool keeps in common the memory.. thus tried with ProcessPool, but still won run the whole rountine for trouble apart of such formatting missmatching..

I don't know what to think and solve it

thanks for help

Comment: You can e. g. wrap the code in `aggiorna_tit` in a `threading.Lock`. This may affect parallel processing because only one thread can call the function at a time then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I log while using multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python)

Comment: Thanks Marco, Seams yes !. Need to work around but, Iopheam's funcions you linked are very useful.

Comment: I've also learned that multi processing is a kind of little pain in the ass to understand, but also to manage...let's see if its speed up accordingly the speed rations.. Actually its don't seams so much to me..I'm on to concurrently learn huge time series features with a single RNN models at once, working with 4 hard(8 virtual cores) and a 12Gb GPU + 8 Gb Shared mem.  Working with multythreads, and os.cpu_count -1 as core # , both mem are almost fitted but I don't see so much improvement on learned/minute ratio from the serial loop, were gpu works at almost half load. Any advice ?